# SSIS - XML Validation Error - "Expected schema root"

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML Task within an SSIS package that is giving me the following error when run:

```
Error: 0xC002F304 at XML Task, XML Task: An error occurred with the following error
  message: "Expected schema root. Make sure the root element is <schema> and the 
  namespace is 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' for an XSD schema or 
  'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data' for an XDR schema.".
```

Here's an example of the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Item xmlns="http://path.to.namespace.com">
    <Name>Notebook</Name>
    <Price>4.95</Price>
</Item>
```

The XSD document looks like this (reformatted to fit better here - in the actual XSD the schema tag is all one line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               targetNamespace="http://path.to.namespace.com" 
               xmlns="http://path.to.namespace.com" 
               elementFormDefault="qualified">

<!-- id_ps -->
<xs:element name="Item">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:decimal"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I've run the XSD/XML combo through a few online validators and it seems to be just fine. I've even taken out all file connections and done Direct Input for both the XML and XSD on the task to rule out any file permissions - exact same error.

Here is my XML Task configuration:

```
Input
  Operation Type:         Validate
  Source Type:            Direct Input
  Source:                 (see above XML)

Output
  SaveOperationResult:    False

Second Operand
  SecondOperandType:      Direct Input
  SecondOperand:          (see above XSD)

Validation options
  ValidationType:         XSD
  FailOnValidationFail:   False
```

I don't have a ton of experience with XML/XSD, and the XSD was generated by a third party vendor.

Is there anything that I'm just totally missing here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] the exhibits this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes I have added examples for the XML and XSD documents - let me know if they are not complete enough.

Comment: Your XSD and XML are fine.  Suspect the configuration of your SSIS task.  Unless there's a well-known trouble spot there that someone can tell you to check, you'll probably have to include the SSIS XML task configuration in MCVE form in order for anyone to be able to reproduce the problem.  Are you certain that the above XSD-XML pair are being read and not some other pair?

Comment: @kjhughes yes, the above pair is being read, I'm putting them in as direct inputs. I'll also throw the configuration into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with VB instead within a ScriptTask. It does the following:

1. Takes in the XML as a string variable from the SSIS package.
2. Strips a few tags off that the ExecuteSQLTask adds on.
3. Reads the string into an XMLDocument.
4. Adds the schema from a file path to the XMLDocument.
5. Validates the XML.
6. Writes out the XML using a StreamWriter.

Check it out:

```
Dim XMLstring As String = Dts.Variables("User::XMLvariable").Value.ToString()
Dim XMLdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

'Remove ROOT tags that show up.
XMLstring = XMLstring.Replace("<ROOT>", "")
XMLstring = XMLstring.Replace("</ROOT>", "")

XMLdoc.LoadXml(XMLstring)

XMLdoc.Schemas.Add(Nothing, "XSDFile.xsd")

Try
    XMLdoc.Validate(Nothing)
Catch ex As XmlException
    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "XML Error", "Error:" + ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    Exit Sub
Catch ex As Exception
    Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error", "Error:" + ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    Exit Sub
End Try

Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter("ExportFile.xml")
XMLdoc.Save(sw)
sw.Dispose()
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResult.Success
```

I'm sure there should be more error checking and everything, this is just a simple form of it. Totally open to suggestions and tweaks.

Got help and examples from here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?528172-VB-NET-code-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-file
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10444/Simple-code-to-validate-an-XML-file-against-a-sche